# excel Macro with text box, search for X, then strikeout

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Im working on a fantasy football excel sheet, and am looking for a solution to keeping track of who's already been drafted. I'd like to have a text box which i can put in a players name, then hit enter to search for that player, then strike out the player name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!
Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get started would be to record a macro with the build-in macro recorder. Excel will give you information on the key commands. 
Additionally, check the web for some more information.
I found a macro which does exactly what you are asking for: 
http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win006.htm

You only have to add:

```
With Rng.Font
    .Strikethrough = True
End With
```

Good luck!
S

Answer (score 1):

or you can just record a macro of this:

In `Find and Replace` put what you want to find in both `Find what:` and `Replace with:` fields. Then select the strike trugh in the `Format...` next to the `Replace with:`

[image]